# Sumar las columnas de un vector y almacenarlas en otro vector

Tags: c

Ademas de lo que pregunto tengo que mostrar la suma de las columnas de mayor  a menor (esto es lo que  llevo solo la suma pero el resultado me muestra una serie de números )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int matriz[3][3];
    int suma[3][3], i,c=0,f=0;
    
    for(f=0;f<3;f++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            printf("Intrduzca un numero para la posicion  %d,%d:",f,c );
            scanf("%d", &matriz[f][c]);
        }
    }
    printf("Elementos de la matriz\n");
    for(f=0;f<3;f++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            printf("[%d]",matriz[f][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(c=0;c<3;c++){
        for(f=0;f<3;f++){
         suma[f][c]+=matriz[f][c];
         
         
        }
        printf("\nla suma de la columna %d es: %d", c+1,suma);
        }
    
        
            
        
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es un simple error de lógica, principalmente al declarar la variable `suma` como un array bidimensional, donde solo era necesario declararlo de 1 dimensión (un array) y con 3 espacios para las 3 columnas.

Por otra parte no es una muy buena practica (o no se ve muy bien) declarar varías variables del mismo tipo en una sola línea, si la variable tendrá el mismo valor, puede ser aceptable, pero no mezcles todo.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //has mas entendible las delcaraciones
    int matriz[3][3];
    int suma[3]; //aqui se almacena la suma
    int i,c=0;
    int f=0;
    //... resto del codigo
    for(c=0;c<3;c++){
        int sum = 0; //creamos una variable que almacene la suma de la columna
        for(f=0;f<3;f++){
         sum+=matriz[f][c]; //vamos sumando
        }
        suma[c] = sum; //agregamos el resultado al array
        printf("\nla suma de la columna %d es: %d", c+1,sum); //imprimimos
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable `suma` sólo debe ser un vector unidimensional.
Tus varibles `i`, `c`, `f` son variables de ambito, no deberías declararlos como variables globales; lo que es peor haces `c=0,f=0` y vuelves a inicializar dentro del `for` a cero.
Para la dimensión de tu matríz que es igual a 3, lo mejor es que lo declares como constante, esto porque si quieres cambiar la dimensión diferente a 3 solo cambias el valor de la constante.
Ahora para realizar tus preguntas, necesitas realizar 2 pasos:

1. Recorrer matriz, sumar cada columna de la matriz y guardarlo en un vector.
2. Ordenar el vector de mayor a menor y mostrar sus elementos.

Te dejo el código con las indicaciones propuestas.

```
int const DIM = 3;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int matriz[DIM][DIM]; //matriz
    
    for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            printf("Introduzca un numero para la posicion  %d,%d:",f,c );
            scanf("%d", &matriz[f][c]);
        }
    }
    printf("Elementos de la matriz\n");
    for(int f=0;f<DIM;f++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<DIM;c++)
        {
            printf("[%d]",matriz[f][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    int vectorSuma[DIM];//almacenar la suma de cada suma
    
    //Guardar la suma de cada columna en un vector
    for(int c=0;c<DIM;c++){
        int suma=0; //variable para sumar cada columna
        for(int f=0;f<DIM;f++){
         suma+=matriz[f][c];
        }
        vectorSuma[c]=suma;
        printf("\nla suma de la columna %d es: %d", c+1,suma);
    }
    
    
    //Ordenamos nuestro vectorSuma de mayor a menor 
    int temporal;
    
    for (int i = 0;i < DIM; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< DIM-1; j++){
            if (vectorSuma[j] < vectorSuma[j+1]){ // Ordena el array de mayor a menor, cambiar el "<" a ">" para ordenar de menor a mayor
            temporal = vectorSuma[j]; 
            vectorSuma[j] = vectorSuma[j+1]; 
            vectorSuma[j+1] = temporal;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Mostramos el vectorSuma ordenado de Mayor a Menor
        printf("\n\n\t Mostrando array ordenado \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printf("[%d]",vectorSuma[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: en ningun momento el OP quiere ordenar la matriz

Comment: No estoy ordenando la matriz, estoy ordenando el Array de suma de columnas para mostrar de mayor a menor, eso pide

Comment: ``Ademas de lo que pregunto tengo que mostrar la suma de las columnas de mayor a menor `` . ¿Cómo lo interpreto eso? \_(°-°)_/ –

Comment: jeje, me olvidé de eso, perdón >_<

Comment: jejeje, aveces pasa, saludos

Comment: Eso estuve pensando hermano en la inicialización de las variables para los ciclos ví que lo había hecho 2 veces, ya rectifiqué los errores en base a lo que me has dicho, saludos